# How to add text on top of Dart Flutter gridView?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I made an application like this:

[image]

I want to add a little info text on top of this gridView structure. How can I do it? I'm a beginner and I just couldn't do it.

**Codes:**

```
body: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
    child: GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,

      ),
      itemCount: subjects.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Padding(
          
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          child: Container(
            child: InkWell(
              
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(subjects[index].subjectImage, fit: BoxFit.cover, height: 50, width: 50,),
                      SizedBox(height: 15,),
                      Text(subjects[index].subjectName, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                      
                    ],
                    
                  ),
                  
                ),
                onTap: () {},
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
```

How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to widget like above design? can you show your current design on your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code. I have added text like `Text("1234567890")`

```
body: Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text("1234567890"), //<------------


      Expanded(
        child: GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
          ),
          itemCount: subjects.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
              child: Container(
                child: InkWell(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Image.asset(
                          subjects[index].subjectImage,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          height: 50,
                          width: 50,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          subjects[index].subjectName,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Assertion failed:
`..\…\rendering\box.dart:1927
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#6cbdb relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT"

The relevant error-causing widget was
column
It gives error lib\interfaceScreen.dart:66` and redirects to `box.dart`.

Comment: Code updated. Just `Expanded` your gridview.builder.

Comment: This time, the code of `subjects[index].subjectImage`, gave the error `RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..4: 5)`.

Comment: Ok sorry, Wait a min. Code updated. Try now

Answer (score 1):

You can use @DholaHardik's answer. Just need to wrap the Grid View Builder to a Sized Box and give it a height let's say height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height and if the error says Overyflow by say 45 pixels.. You can change height to MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 45;